# Unable to add folders to PYTHONPATH when creating conda environment

Tags: anaconda, conda, virtualenv, python-import, pythonpath

I have a script that is making a conda virtual environment where functions need to be imported from folders outside of the repo. I have tried two approaches to add the folders to the path:

1. Conda develop:

   os.system(conda run -n test_env conda develop ' + PACKAGE_PATH)

Results in:

> Permission denied [PACKAGE_PATH]

2. Create conda.pth manually

   path = os.path.join(env_path, 'lib')
   if not os.path.exists(path):
   os.mkdir(path)
   path = os.path.join(path, 'site-packages')
   if not os.path.exists(path):
   os.mkdir(path)
   env_path_file = os.path.join(path, 'conda.pth')

   with open(env_path_file, 'w+') as f:
   write_line(f, PACKAGE_PATH)

The file is created successfully. But, setting the conda interpreter from test_env (in Pycharm) and doing import sys; sys.path does not show [PACKAGE_PATH] and functions cannot be imported from its folders.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is resolved by using conda develop from outside the environment:

```
conda develop [package_path]
```

not

```
conda run -n conda develop [package_path]
```